# Remove & quote; and elements of a list ( erlang )

Tags: xml, string, functional-programming, erlang, ejabberd

I have a record list which I want to display as a string, and then pass to an XML attribute:

```
Li = (get the record),
```

LOOKS LIKE:

```
?INFO_MSG("LIST::::: ~p~n", [?SETS:to_list(Li)]),
[{"9993939","some.com",[]}, {"12341234","some.com",[]}]
```

I remove some duplicates with :

```
Li = ?SETS:to_list(List)
Set = sets:from_list(Li)
O = sets:to_list(Set)
```

after this I use io_lib:format to get my final string:

```
OO = io_lib:format("~p", [O])
```

but when I provide it to the XML it comes with & quote; characters,

```
"[{& quote;9993939& quote;,& quote;some.com& quote;,[]},{&
quote;12341234&& quote;,& quote;some.com& quote;,[]}]"
```

how can I remove those characters?

Actually my final goal

from this:

```
"[{"9993939","some.com",[]}, {"12341234","some.com",[]}]"
```

get only the numbers on the list:

```
"[9993939,12341234]"
```

Comment: Could you post the actual code? This is very confuse. Did you try to use ~s instead of ~p on the io_lib:format?

Comment: yes and still get the & quot; instead of "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague... hard to understand, but is this what you want?

```
-module(vague).
-compile(export_all).

extract(Li)->
    [Element || {ok, [Element],[]} <- [io_lib:fread("~d", Projection) ||
                                          {Projection, _, _} <- Li]].


1> vague:extract([{"9993939","some.com",[]}, {"12341234","some.com",[]}]).
   [9993939, 12341234]
```

Comment: this is what I wanted, but how can I remove & quots; ?. This is the code I use to convert it to string OO = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [ListO])), but it displays as "[& quot;9993939& quot;,& quot;12341234& quot;]"

Comment: alright this helped me with the issue http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/How-to-remove-from-string-td3431087.html

Comment: take a look at by modified response, it might be more helpful